# how to write a trigger to insert and update unique varchar field.....?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table named `contact`:

```
Create table contact (
    Contact_ID int PK NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(20),
    MMS_Contact_ID varchar(10) NOT NULL
)
```

When am inserting the first 2 rows, `Contact_ID` and `Name`, i want to automatically update the third row (`MMS_Contact_ID`). Like this:

```
contact_ID    Name     MMS_Contact_ID
--------------------------------------           
1               A        MMSC000001
```

When am inserting the second record (id = 2 and Name = B), how can 
`MMS_Contact_ID` automatically be updated to MMSC000002?

I think a trigger can help me with this, but how?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
create trigger trupdcont before insert on contact for each row

set new.MMS_Contact_ID := 'MMSC' + LPAD(convert(varchar, new.Contact_ID), 6, '0');
```

Before the insert, the trigger checks the `max contact_id` and `update` the third column to be `"MMSC" + max(contact_id)+1` (with trailling zeros assigned by the `LPAD`).

Comment: @thavan you are right, and I don't need to accept the value. It's on `contact_id` column :)

Answer (score 0):

Adapting @aF's answer, I think the select is a) unnecessary and b) a race condition, so:

```
create trigger trupdcont after insert on contact for each row
set new.MMS_Contact_ID := 'MMSC' + LPAD(convert(varchar, new.contact_ID), 6, '0');
```

the AFTER INSERT trigger already has the auto-incremented ID

Comment: Yes, you are right :) I've edit my as well. In your answer, it's `Contact_ID` and not `contact_ID`.

Comment: Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger.... i got error... but i want to result like when am inserting first two columns data 3 rd column data genrate automaticall... how to get 3rd column data automatically